# Check if username exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that will be triggered on `blur` and send ajax request to check if username already exist in database. So far function works fine but I found one problem when user tries to update already saved username. Here is example of my code:

```js
var usernames = ["jcook","mjones","kruffy"];

$(".check-account").focus(function() {
  var submitBtn = $(this).closest("form").find(":submit");
  submitBtn.prop("disabled", true); //Disable submit button on field focus.
  $(this).attr('data-prev', $(this).val()); // Save current value in data attribute as data-prev.
  if(!$(this).data("original")){
    $(this).data("original",$(this).val());
  } 
}).blur(function() {
  var fldObj = $(this),
      submitBtn = $(this).closest("form").find(":submit");

  if (fldObj.val() !== fldObj.data('prev') && fldObj.val() !== fldObj.data("original")) {
      if ($.inArray(fldObj.val(), usernames) === -1) {
        fldObj.data("original","");
        fldObj[0].setCustomValidity("");
      } else {
        fldObj[0].setCustomValidity("User name already exist.");
      }
      submitBtn.prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    fldObj[0].setCustomValidity("");
    submitBtn.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="frm_recordid" id="frm_recordid">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="username"><span class="label label-default">UserName:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control check-account is-user" name="frm_username" id="frm_username" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
      <div id="frm_message" class="alert"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you run my code example above you will see that my function will catch username if already exist. The problem that I have is when I try to edit data. Let's say I open form and user name will have value `jcook`. Then I try to enter different username for example `mjones`. If I try to submit form I will get message `Username already exist!`. Then if I try to put `jcook` again my code will trigger same message even I just try to put the same value that was already in the field for that record. I'm wondering how to avoid function trigger in this case if username was already saved for that record?

Comment: Offtopic: Instead of `$(this).attr('data-prev', $(this).val())` use `.data()` eg `$(this).data('prev', $(this).val())` and `$(this).data("prev")`

Comment: You store the "current" value, why not store the "original" value in the same manner, when you first generate the form

Comment: @Variable Would that change anything?

Comment: @freedomn-m Your first comment, would that change anything using `.data()` instead of '.attr()'. Second, can you please provide example on how to store original data?

Comment: `.data()` is handled internally by jquery, so is vastly more efficient than setting `.attr()` which has to change the DOM.  It's also just good practice.  (but doesn't help your issue, hence the offtopic tag)

Comment: `$(function() { $(".check-account").data("original-value", $(".check-account").val()); });`

Comment: How that will help with my problem? Compare that to current value like I do already so my if statement would look like this: `if (currVal !== prevVal && curVal !== orinialVal) {`

Comment: I found solution. So far works for me but might not be the best. I have updated working example above.

Comment: You described your problem as:  start with X, change to Y "Y in use", change to X "X in use".  Keeping the original value ("X") would remove that last issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m There is more fields in my form, this is just small example. So I have to let user change other data/fields on the form and submit the data. Example above works fine so far but I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you.